# How to bind sendmail outgoing mail to a specific local IP or or used domain IP

Tags: ip, sendmail

I dont know hos to setup Sendmail for outgoing mail use a specific local IP or or used domain IP.

Ex : 
4 Ips :

- 192.168.1.100 (default) bind to host.domain0.com
- 192.168.1.101 bind to mail.domain1.com
- 192.168.1.102 bind to mail.domain2.com
- 192.168.1.103 bind to mail.domain3.com

And I whould like than any user who send email using mail.domain1.com use mail.domain1.com / 192.168.1.101 as outgoning and not the default one / 192.168.1.100 .

EX from the current mail header for any domain : from host.domain0.com (host.domain0.com [192.168.1.100])

I see some feature like Mailertables, but can find an example who explain if it's the right feature for my problem.

Thanks a lot for your help.
Mike

Answer (score 1):

In fact I found the answer, and I hope it will be useful for other.

I simply add "b" to the Modifiers list in the DAEMON_OPTIONS. 
Ex : DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Name=MSA,Port=submission,Modifiers=abE')

By this way the sender who use mail.domain1.com as SMTP, the SMTP send now mail.domain1.com as mail server sender's host.

Simple, but hard to find a doc explain this process.

Mike